# Disjoint set with equal number of records from 2 tables

Tags: sql

I have 2 similar tables

```
TBL-1
-----
Userid, score

TBL-2
-----
Userid, score
```

Each having a score based on a different algorithm, I need to create a dataset that has equal number records from 2 datasets that are also disjoint, what is the efficient(execution time) way to do this?

EDIT:1: One important pointer, both tables exactly the same userids(almost), but with scores from different algorithms

PS: I know I can run a `NOT IN(CTE/sub-query)` but also think it is not the best solution

Comment: what is the goal of having two separated table for this data.

Comment: I have them given that way :) .. Nothing I can change now.. But also will I not have the same problem with one single table and two different score and having to select a disjoint set..

Comment: *" I need to create a dataset that has equal number records from 2 datasets that are also disjoint"* See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What do you mean "disjoint"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff The userids from table 1 should not be picked from table 2 and I shall pick only a subset of records fro table 1

Comment: *"The userids from table 1 should not be picked from table 2 and I shall pick only a subset of records fro table 1 "* *"I know I can run a NOT IN(CTE/sub-query) but also think it is not the best solution "* i think the best is using `a LEFT JOIN b... WHERE b.<column> IS NOT NULL` assuming you make indexes.

Comment: @RaymondNijland both tables will contain the same ids, only the scores will be different, so I will have all the rows(userids)  with both scores after left join, but now I need to pick a subset with t1_score and another with t2_score (and a flag column to indicate which is what), but still, I have to ensure that the 2 sets are disjoint, may be naively with a NOT IN() is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky.  I think starting with a `full join` and then some enumeration works.  The idea is to enumerate the users in the overlap set.  Half of these go on each side using modulo arithmetic.

Then, calculate the minimum number of "extra" rows.  The smaller number is taken from both sets.

```
select coalesce(userid1, userid2) as userid,
       (case when userid1 is null then score2
             when userid2 is null then score1
             when both_seqnum % 2 = 0 then score1
             else score2
        end) as score,
       (case when userid1 is null then 'tbl_2'
             when userid2 is null then 'tbl_1'
             when both_seqnum % 2 = 0 then 'tbl_1'
             else 'tbl_2'
        end) as which
from (select t1.userid as userid1, t2.userid as userid2, t1.score as score1, t2.score as score2,
             (case when count(t1.userid) over () < count(t2.userid) over ()
                   then sum(case when t1.userid is not null and t2.userid is null then 1 else 0 end)
                   else sum(case when t2.userid is not null and t1.userid is null then 1 else 0 end)
              end)
             ) as extra_count,                  
             (case when t1.userid is not null and t2.userid is null
                   then row_number() over (partition by (case when t1.userid is not null and t2.userid is not null then 1 else 0 end)
                                           order by userid
                                          )
              end) as t1_seqnum,
             (case when t1.userid is null and t2.userid is not null
                   then row_number() over (partition by (case when t1.userid is not null and t2.userid is not null then 1 else 0 end)
                                           order by userid
                                          )
              end) as t2_seqnum,
             (case when t1.userid is not null and t2.userid is not null
                   then row_number() over (partition by (case when t2.userid is not null then 1 else 0 end)
                                           order by (case when t1.userid is null then 1 else 0 end)
                                          )
              end) as both_seqnum
      from tbl1 t1 full join
           tbl2 t2
           on t1.userid = t2.userid
     ) t12
where (t1.userid1 is not null and t2.userid1 is not null) or
      (t1.userid1 is not null and t1.seqnum <= extra_count) or
      (t1.userid2 is not null and t2.seqnum <= extra_count)
```

Comment: t2_seqnum is missing in the above query is it ```(case when t2.userid is not null and t1.userid is null
                   then row_number() over (partition by (case when t2.userid is not null and t1.userid not null then 1 else 0 end)
                                           order by userid
                                          )
              end) as t2_seqnum```

Answer (score 0):

Use a full outer join and colaesce the ID columns to compare the scores from table to table

```
select coalesce(t1.UserID, t2.UserID) as userid,
       t1.score as t1_score,
       t2.score as t2_score
from Tbl1 t1
full outer join tbl2 t2
on t1.userid = t2.userid
```

Or, to find the occurrences that don't match between tables (find all t1 without a matching t2, and vice versa):

```
select t1.UserID, t1.score, 'T1' as source_tab
from t1
where not exists (select 1 from t2 where t2.UserID = t1.userID and t1.score = t2.score)

union all

select t2.UserID, t2.score, 'T2' as source_tab
from t2
where not exists (select 1 from t1 where t2.UserID = t1.userID and t1.score = t2.score)
```

Comment: In this case, I will a dataset with both scores, but I need to pick a subset with t1_score and another with t2_score (and a flag column to indicate which is what), but still, I have to ensure that the 2 sets are disjoint, may be naively with a NOT IN() is there a better way to do this?